# Add two different numbers in a single text field space separated in Access VBA

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I am using Access and VBA to tidy up a database before a migration. One field is going from text to an INT. So I need to convert and possibly add some numbers which exist in a singular field.

Examples:

```
F/C 3 other 8          should become 11
Calender-7             should become  7
21 F/C and 1 other     should become 22
29 (natural ways)      should become 29
```

The second and fourth line are simple enough, just use the following regex in VBA

```
Dim rgx As New RegExp
Dim inputText As String
Dim outputText As String
rgx.Pattern = "[^0-9]*"
rgx.Global = True

inputText = "29 (natural ways)"
outputText = rgx.Replace(inputText, "")
```

The downside is if I use it on option 1 or 3:

```
F/C 3 other 8          will become  38
Calender-7             will become   7
21 F/C and 1 other     will become 211
29 (natural ways)      will become  29
```

This is simple enough in bash, I can just keep the spaces by adding one to [^0-9 ]* and then piping it into awk which will add every field using a space as a delimiter like so:

```
sed 's/[^0-9 ]*//g' | awk -F' ' 's=0; {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) s=s+$i; print s}'
F/C 3 other 8          will become 11
21 F/C and 1 other     will become 22
```

The problem is I cannot use bash, and there are far too many values to do it by hand. Is there any way to use VBA to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the replace method, just capture and then add up all the numbers.  For example:

```
    Option Explicit
Function outputText(inputText)
Dim rgx As RegExp
Dim mc As MatchCollection, m As Match
Dim I As Integer

Set rgx = New RegExp
rgx.Pattern = "[0-9]+"
rgx.Global = True

Set mc = rgx.Execute(inputText)
    For Each m In mc
        I = I + CInt(m) 'may Need to be cast as an int in Access VBA; not required in Excel VBA
    Next m

outputText = I
End Function
```

Comment: After casting M as and int, it worked great. Here are some examples of the output (alternating between before string and after int):
"Calender-9"
9
"F/C 10"
10
"Calender-7"
7
"F/C 3 other 8"
11
"F/C 10 other 8"
18`

Comment: @TimothyHarding  I'm surprised you had to do that CInt.  Of course, I was testing using VBA running under Excel, where, since I was of type integer, the value of m was coerced as the same.  Possibly that doesn't happen with Access VBA

Comment: I am also a bit confused, I thought using option explicit would keep a type change from happening, or is that option strict. Yup, if I run it as is I get a whole lot of this: 033
0384
076
012
06
01
And the values are combined rather than added. But it was a quick fix and it works beautifully, thanks!

Comment: @TimothyHarding Option Strict is not available in VBA.  Option explicit requires declaration of all variables.  I don't have Access so can't run a test in that environment.  But glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are any easier way for your question. Here I've wrote small function for you.

Requirement: add all numbers in a string, **identify "consecutive" digits as one number.**

pseudo:

1. Loop through given text
2. find the first number and check/loop if following chars are numbers
3. if following chars are numbers treat as one number else pass the
   result
4. continue searching from last point and add the result to the total

in code:

```
Public Function ADD_NUMB(iText As String) As Long
    Dim I, J As Integer
    Dim T As Long
    Dim TM As String

    For I = 1 To Len(iText)
        If (InStr(1, "12346567890", Mid$(iText, I, 1)) >= 1) Then
            TM = Mid(iText, I, 1)
            For J = I + 1 To Len(iText)
                If (InStr(1, "12346567890", Mid$(iText, J, 1)) >= 1) Then
                    TM = TM & Mid$(iText, J, 1)
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next J
            T = T + Val(Nz(TM, 0))
            I = J
        End If
    Next I
    ADD_NUMB = T
End Function
```

usage:

```
 dim total as integer
total = ADD_NUMB("21 F/C and 1 other")
```

not sure about performance but it will get you what you need :)